# Bitcoin open source web wallet with Bitcoin wallet service

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, bip32-hd-wallets

Where the user email and password are stored when user registered on the web wallet websites like blockchain.com ?

Is the blockchain.com directly interact with the bitcoin blockchain and store the email and password on blockchain ??

How the web wallet works ? How they are interact with the blockchain ?

Sorry for lots of questions in one , The main thing that i want to understand how the more secured web wallet interact with blockchain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where the user email and password are stored when user registered on
>   the web wallet websites like blockchain.com ?

In the [`ORDBMS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_database) database.

> Is the blockchain.com directly interact with the bitcoin blockchain
>   and store the email and password on blockchain ??

The blockchain.com has full bitcoin node and interact directly with bitcoin node. They doesnt store users data(email, passwords and so on) in the blockchain

> How the web wallet works ? How they are interact with the blockchain ?

Web wallets is a plain middleware between full nodes and users, they are in the cloud.

> How the more secured web wallet interact with blockchain ?

Your wallet is protected, but there is always a chance what this web wallet(or any other web service which offers web wallets) will be hacked.

Comment: The blockchain.com has full bitcoin node and interact directly with bitcoin node. They doesnt store users data(email, passwords and so on) in the blockchain
   While creating account on blockchain.com they ask for email and password and after that they are providing the 36 chracters id for login ?

Comment: @PankajKumar maybe, I dont use web wallets.

Comment: how can we generate the mnemonics with bitcoin RPC ?

Comment: The genertion of mnemonics currently in proposed bips https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki

Comment: Is its in purposal then how some of the website are using the 12 words character to unlock the wallet ?

Comment: There are plenty implementations https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki#other-implementations